# Controlling "Usage & Diagnostics" in Android

Tags: android, google-api, android-developer-api, android-settings, android-api-levels

Is there a way to control the automatic sending of diagnostics and usage data to Google in Android device. I could see the switch with "Usage & Diagnostics" in device settings, but need to control it via an application. Any API key exposed by Android?

Comment: why somebody down voted this question ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot because that would be a huge privacy violation.